# HTML Form and input Data

Tags: html, get, request

I am trying to send a GET request to  " ...:8000/find/alvin/ "

using a Form I created with the html code below

```html
<form method="get" 
      style="position:absolute;right:0" 
      rel="search" 
      action="/find/">
      
  <input type="text" 
      class=" form-control"  
      name="value" 
      placeholder="Search⌕"/>  
      
  <button type="submit" class="d-none" >SUBMIT</button>
  
</form>
```

,However after typing a name, and hitting the submit button, I am sent to "...:8000/find/?value=alvin/ "

, how would I send a GET request to my desired URL using a form , a input of type text, and a submit button ?

Any help is truly appreciated ,
thank you for taking the time to read my question

sincerely,
hugo shcottss

Comment: Eh? What's the question? Address `...:8000/find/?value=alvin/` is right using this form.

Comment: would there be a better way to write this form? to get me to this address "...:8000/find/alvin "  if at all possible

Comment: No, this form is okay (can't be written better), use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to do your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing the form data in a query string is the normal way of passing data using a form.

If you want to change it to use URLs of the style you are using then there are two approaches:

## HTTP redirects

1. Let the form submit to the URL using a query string.
2. Read the query string using server-side code
3. Generate the URL you want
4. Respond with a `302 Found` status code and a `Location` header with the new URL in it

(You can use any language you like for this, and some servers have modules which can be configured to do this (e.g. mod_rewrite) without using an actual programming language).

## JavaScript

1. Listen for a submit event on the form
2. Prevent the default behaviour of a form submission
3. Read the values from the form fields
4. Construct the new URL
5. Assign the new URL to `location` so the browser navigates to it

---

Either way, make sure you escape any values you put in the URL so that the user typing characters with special meaning into the form won't cause you any problems.